# Sort Column using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have created Excel sheet and written data into Excel file.

Do we have any functionality for sort column using `openpyxl`?
I could not attach Excel sheet and droping one row of excel sheet:

```
0   -269.9  99.97   0   -25.58  0   0.0006901   -269.9  127 0   26.23   0   810 -269.9
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46313587/1072869 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247373/sort-a-range-of-cells-win32com-client to see how to sort using `win32com`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no such thing in [openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/) or [xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/) or even [xlsxwriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter) (but if you're on windows, you can [do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311345/manipulating-excel-2007-files-using-python) via win32com and `Excel.Application`).

Usually, you should just read the data from the excel file, sort it in python and write the data back.

See similar questions:

- [how to sort xls file column wise and write it to another file with entire row using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125465/how-to-sort-xls-file-column-wise-and-write-it-to-another-file-with-entire-row-us)
- [xlrd / xlutils reordering spreadsheet rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632858/xlrd-xlutils-reordering-spreadsheet-rows?lq=1)

Comment: This is correct. I can confirm that sorting **isn't** part of the file format and thus can't be done with the Python Excel file creation modules.