# Sort a Range of Cells, win32com.client

Tags: python, sorting, range, win32com

I am trying to sort a range of cells in python using win32com:

[image]

Code I've been using is:

```
sheet.Range("A1:B8").Sort(Key1=sheet.Range("B1"), Orientation=constants.xlAscending)
```

which is working. It sorts the range of cells by the second column:

[image]

When I want, is to sort Descending instead of Ascending:

```
sheet.Range("B8:A1").Sort(Key1=sheet.Range("B1"), Orientation=constants.xlDescending)
```

but for some weird reason, it switches the data from each column and doesn't sort the values that were initially in the second column.

[image]

I've played with a ton of different parameters types sot the sort method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) but nothing seems to work. Has anyone have experience with this method and can suggest how I would get the second column sort descending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your orientation argument should either be: `xlSortColumns = 1` or `xlSortRows = 2`. See below Python script adjustment. As the [Range.Sort Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) shows, *Order1*, *Order2*, and *Order3* takes the `xlAscending = 1` or `xlDescending = 2` values.

```
import win32com.client

wbk = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Workbook.xlsx'

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(wbk)

xlAscending = 1
xlSortColumns = 1    
xlApp.Sheets(1).Columns("A:B").Sort(Key1=xlApp.Sheets(1).Range("B1"),
                                    Order1=xlAscending, Orientation=xlSortColumns)

xlApp.Quit
xlApp = None
```

Comment: That's great Parfait. That gets me basically what I want, with one exception. I need a range of cells, as opposed to whole columns, so taking your suggestion and instead of xl.App.Columns("A:B")  I substituted xlApp.Range("A1:G9")